# "failed to retrieve database [GeoLite2-Country.mmdb]" on k8s cluster when installed elastic cluster using helm

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, elk

I installed elastic cluster using helm on k8s cluster and got the following error. Not able to figure out where the issue is.

helm install elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch -f values-aws.yaml

**elasticsearch-8.5.1**

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-05-16T01:22:09.414Z", "log.level":"ERROR", "message":"failed to retrieve database [GeoLite2-City.mmdb]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-master-0][generic][T#2]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.DatabaseNodeService","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch","error.type":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException","error.message":"blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];"
```

values-aws.yaml:

```html
# Shrink default JVM heap.
esJavaOpts: "-Xmx128m -Xms128m"

# Allocate smaller chunks of memory per pod.
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: "100m"
    memory: "512M"
  limits:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "512M"

# To allocate more space if above requests and limits aren't enough
# resources:
  # requests:
    # cpu: "500m"
    # memory: "2Gi"
  # limits:
    # cpu: "1000m"
    # memory: "5G"

# Request smaller persistent volumes.
volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  storageClassName: "efs-sc"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100M
```

k8s Cluster is installed on AWS nodes.

Comment: After increasing allocated CPU and Memory resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We were having that issue in our elastic search cluster v7.17.1 running on EKS cluster v1.21.0, and helm v3.6.3, all three pods were running over 284 days, then we had to perform a `helm upgrade`. The first pod got running stuck but the health check process was failing, hence the ELK cluster was not getting on GREEN state. Checking the logs of the failing pod that the problem was related to the download of downloading of geoip database, like the message below:

`geoip database [GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb] to [/tmp/elasticsearch-9470345091343635510/geoip-databases/HoGUMQ9ISsCjQ4KhIL2IFA/GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb.tmp.gz]" }`

Describing the pod, we notice to consider the pod healthy, the pod's health check verify if the empty file `/tmp/.es_start_file` exists, but for some reason this file were not being created. Health check code below:

```
START_FILE=/tmp/.es_start_file

# Disable nss cache to avoid filling dentry cache when calling curl
# This is required with Elasticsearch Docker using nss < 3.52
export NSS_SDB_USE_CACHE=no

http () {
  local path="${1}"
  local args="${2}"
  set -- -XGET -s

  if [ "$args" != "" ]; then
    set -- "$@" $args
  fi

  if [ -n "${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}" ]; then
    set -- "$@" -u "elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}"
  fi

  curl --output /dev/null -k "$@" "https://127.0.0.1:9200${path}"
}

if [ -f "${START_FILE}" ]; then
  echo 'Elasticsearch is already running, lets check the node is healthy'
  HTTP_CODE=$(http "/" "-w %{http_code}")
  RC=$?
  if [[ ${RC} -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "curl --output /dev/null -k -XGET -s -w '%{http_code}' \${BASIC_AUTH} https://127.0.0.1:9200/ failed with RC ${RC}"
    exit ${RC}
  fi
  # ready if HTTP code 200, 503 is tolerable if ES version is 6.x
  if [[ ${HTTP_CODE} == "200" ]]; then
    exit 0
  elif [[ ${HTTP_CODE} == "503" && "7" == "6" ]]; then
    exit 0
  else
    echo "curl --output /dev/null -k -XGET -s -w '%{http_code}' \${BASIC_AUTH} https://127.0.0.1:9200/ failed with HTTP code ${HTTP_CODE}"
    exit 1
  fi

else
  echo 'Waiting for elasticsearch cluster to become ready (request params: "wait_for_status=green&timeout=5s" )'
  if http "/_cluster/health?wait_for_status=green&timeout=5s" "--fail" ; then
    touch ${START_FILE}
    exit 0
  else
    echo 'Cluster is not yet ready (request params: "wait_for_status=green&timeout=5s" )'
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

So we get a shell into the container pod, and crated manually using the `touch /tmp/.es_start_file` command. Then the pod became up and running.

Obviously that everything is gonna be fine until the pod restart for some reason, so this is just a workaround for while. I hope can help someone since we have found nothing to help with that problem.